# Binning events with weights

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two  vectors, one containing sampled energies and the other one for each of these energies a weight: `e(i)` and `w(i)`.

I bin the energies `e(i)`. Now I want to compute the sum of weights `w` in each bin separately.

I can bin the energies using `BinLists` and make a plot with `Histogram`. How do I perform the sum over weights in each bin? I would obviously need access to the indices `i` in each bin.

Any elegant solution to this problem would be welcome.

```
e = {0.129454, 0.160294, 0.140456, 0.152359, 0.174006, 0.186969};
w = {2.12373*10^-6, 0.00029488, 5.68648*10^-6, 0.000100244, 2.28126*10^-6, 6.74131*10^-6};
```

Comment: e = {{0.129454, 0.160294, 0.140456, 0.152359, 0.174006, 0.186969}
w = {2.12373*10^-6, 0.00029488, 5.68648*10^-6, 0.000100244, 2.28126*10^-6, 6.74131*10^-6}

Answer (score 3):

Very similar to @Sjoerd's, but relaxing the uniqueness assumption:

```
SeedRandom[42];
n = 20;
bins = {1, 30, 50, 80, 100};
e = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, n];
w = RandomInteger[{1, 3}, n];
k = {#[[1, 1]], Tr[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@    GatherBy[Transpose[{e, w}], First];
wTotal = Tr /@ (Union /@ BinLists[e, {bins}] /. Rule @@@ k)
(*
  {9, 12, 5, 10}
*)

Show[Histogram[e, {bins}], 
     ListLinePlot[Transpose[{MovingAverage[bins, 2], wTotal}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `WeightedData` and `HistogramDistribution`:

@belisarius's example:

```
 SeedRandom[42];
 n = 20;
 e = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, n];
 w = RandomInteger[{1, 3}, n];
 wd = WeightedData[e, w];
 binlimits = {1, 30, 50, 80, 100};
 dist = HistogramDistribution[wd, {binlimits}];
 Total[w] Normalize[dist["PDFValues"], Total]
 (* {9,12,5,10} *)
```

OP and Sjoerd's example:

```
 e2 = {0.129454, 0.160294, 0.140456, 0.152359, 0.174006, 0.186969};
 w2 = {2.12373*10^-6, 0.00029488, 5.68648*10^-6, 0.000100244, 2.28126*10^-6, 6.74131*10^-6};
 wd2 = WeightedData[e2, w2];
 dist2 = HistogramDistribution[wd2, {0.12, .22, 0.03}];
 Total[w2] Normalize[dist2["PDFValues"], Total]
 (* {7.81021*10^-6, 0.000397405, 6.74131*10^-6} *)
```

**Update:** a function to get the total weights of bins:

```
 bwF = Total[#2] Normalize[HistogramDistribution[WeightedData[#1, #2], #3]["PDFValues"], 
            Total] &

 bwF[e, w, {binlimits}]
 (* {9, 12, 5, 10} *)
 bwF[e2, w2,  {0.12, .22, 0.03}]
 (*  {7.81021*10^-6, 0.000397405, 6.74131*10^-6} *)
```

Comment: Nice! How could I have forgotten WeightedData?

Comment: Same here. +1, of course

Comment: @Sjoerd & belisarius thank you both.

Comment: What does 'PDFValues' in Normalize[dist2["PDFValues"], Total] do? Cannot find anything on this in the documentation on Normalize. Where can I find anything on this PDFValues?

Comment: @user3584513, `dist["Properties"]` gives the available properties for the object `dist`. and `dist["PDFValues"]` gives the density for each of the bins. For the first example, `dist["PDFValues"]` returns `{9/851,12/851,5/851,10/851}`, that is the density of the bin `[1,30]` is `9/851` etc. This value is the probability of the interval `[1,30]` divided by the bin length (i.e. `Probability[1<=x<=30, x\[Distributed] dist]/(30-1)`) (similarly for the other bins). `Normalize[xx, Total]` is `xx/Total[xx]` which transforms the `PDFValues` to proportions that add up to 1. ...

Comment: ... Then we multiply these proportions with the the total weight of all observations (`Total[w]`) to get the weight for each bin. Hope this answers your question(s).

Comment: @kugler: many thanks for your explanations. I love that function bwF. It surely works, even though I do not fully understand yet why.

Answer (score 1):

```
e = {0.129454, 0.160294, 0.140456, 0.152359, 0.174006, 0.186969};
w = {2.12373*10^-6, 0.00029488, 5.68648*10^-6, 0.000100244, 2.28126*10^-6, 6.74131*10^-6};

Total /@ (BinLists[e, {0.12, .22, 0.03}] /. Thread[e -> w])
(* {7.81021*10^-6, 0.00039740526, 6.74131*10^-6} *)
```

So, what happens here? `BinList` divides `e` in bins. I then replace every `e` value with the corresponding weight. `Thread` takes care that the rule `->` is taken element-wise. One assumption that is used here: The `e` values should be unique, or more precise: the weights of identical elements in `e` should be identical.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! This really helped. I only wished that Mathematica had a special command for this operation. It does not seem to be so rare!

Comment: What does 'PDFValues' in

Normalize[dist2["PDFValues"], Total]

do? Cannot find anything on this in the documentation on Normalize. Where can I find anything on this PDFValues?